Simple user database / LDAP lookup options for containers
In my environment we launch containers with a specific uid/gid that our users use as workspaces. It's a bit finicky and one of the drawbacks is that there won't be a matching user in /etc/passwd, causing all kinds of havoc.
I was thinking of just maintaining a shared /etc/passwd, storing it in a secret file and then mounting on top of the container's file.
The above approach doesn't seem very robust, so I looked into other nss option such as sssd. We have AD setup so integrating with that would be ideal. After some research I found that sssd is not easy to setup within a container and is meant to be run with root privileges so it may be a dead end.
Are there any other more lightweight alternatives for our use case? We don't really need authentication just the ability to do LDAP lookups for uid/gids.

The package libnss-ldap lets you use ldap directly via nsswitch.conf without needing sssd or nscd.  It may take some working out how to configure the ldap client to talk to AD, but it should be doable!  It's the old-school pre-sssd way :-)

@StephenHarris I have seen libnss-ldap before, maybe I'll try that.
